# How can I check if an empty line is being skipped by Logstash during indexing into Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, logstash, kibana, logstash-configuration

I have a log file containing 2044 lines, but after indexing into Elasticsearch using Logstash, I find only 2043 documents. I suspect that an empty line in the log file might have been skipped by Logstash during indexing.

I'm seeking advice on how to verify if this empty line was indeed ignored by Logstash during processing.

I've checked Logstash logs, but I haven't found specific indications regarding this empty line. Additionally, I've attempted to start Logstash in debug mode, but I'm uncertain what to look for in the logs.

Comment: Could you check if the last document is indexed ? Just to make sure you do not have a weird behavior around the end of the file.

Comment: The last log in my file is not indexed as a document!

Comment: Ahaaaaa typical, you need an extra `\n` at the end of the file

Comment: Can you explain to me please

Comment: Add a new line at the end of your file.